# Why are gerbes so scarce in recent research?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, poisson-geometry, lie-groupoids

I have recently been exposed to gerbes for an undergraduate research project and I feel like this structure has very little mention anywhere really. Most papers that deal with anything relating to it are from the early 2000's and after 2009 or so, there's basically nothing. Why is this? Has it become a dead subject? Is it devoid of application? Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: [According to arXiv](https://arxiv.org/search/math?query=gerbe&searchtype=all&abstracts=show&order=-announced_date_first&size=50), there have been ~20 papers dealing with gerbes uploaded this year. While that's not a ton in relative terms ("birational" gives ~6 time the results for this year), I would push back a little bit on the statement that it's "basically nothing". On the other hand, every time I've talked to someone who works with gerbes, my impression has been that I'm glad they do that work and that I don't, so maybe that contributes.

Comment: I thought it was a neat subject when I heard about it.  If I remember correctly they are fiber bundles in which the fibres are categories.  That's a marriage of two difficult subjects though, to sort of echo @KReiser.  Alice Chang had done some work on the subject.  She was at UCLA in the 90's when I was there, and later was head of the department at Princeton.

Comment: The Brauer group is arguably one of the most important invariants of a field. Although it usually defined using central simple algebras, it is equal to the set of isomorphism classes of $\mathbb{G}_m$-gerbes over your field. Thus, if you study Brauer groups, then you are studying gerbes.

Comment: Gerbes are really ubiquitous in mathematics. If you study line bundles, then you are basically studying $\mathbb{G}_m$-torsors. Studying $\mathbb{G}_m$-gerbes can be interpreted as studying a "higher" version of line bundles. This is also apparent in the fact that the Picard group is $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^\times)$ and that the set of isom classes of $\mathbb{G}_m$-gerbes is $H^2(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$. (Cohomology is here to be interpreted in fppf or etale topology.) What I am saying is that if you study higher cohomology groups of sheaves such as $\mathbb{G}_m$ you are inevitably studying gerbes.